# После изменения urls.py и views.py сервер не работает нужным образом. В чем ошибка?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-view

После изменения urls.py и views.py сервер не работает нужным образом. В чем ошибка?

urls.py в приложении

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, 'index'),]
```

urls.py в "голове"

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
path('', include('posts.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
    output = []
    for item in latest:
        output.append(item.text)
    return HttpResponse('\n'.join(output))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слишком мало информацию. предоставьте больше. хотя бы прокрутите страницу ниже и покажите выделенные блоки. вохможно нужно добавить `name='index'` вместо `'index'`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса